Is there a way to drain websocket in boost asio?
I am using asio/beast for tcp ssl connections. Calling async_read in a loop inside corouties.
In situations when I have N packets on websocket I need to do N async_reads to drain the websocket. This sometimes creates over-scheduling bottleneck for me when throughput is high. Is there a way to copy all data available on the ws with single read, or any other way to avoid over-scheduling?

Can you demonstrate that the async_read is the bottleneck? This might be a code snippet that we can improve, or reduce in a issue to file

Adding a bounty doesn't really make this question more answerable. You could also make a mock ws endpoint that generates a load that you struggle to consume on the C++ side, I'll give it a go.

To give you a bit of context. If I want to copy all data from ws without scheduling, is there a way at least to know there is data on ws so I can copy it with read and not async_read to avoid scheduling?

You shouldn't need to worry about that. You can trust dispatch on the strand to optimize this if the same thread is available. If there's a single thread, you can trust it even more and give the corresponding concurrency hint at io_context construction. The way to know there's data is have an async_read pending.

I do do that, using unsafe concurrency hint which is the most relaxed one.
Still when throughput is high I am losing to another similar application written in C# which can copy data from ws with batches. On low throughput I am actually faster.

Again, I'd love to have something tangible to test/test against. I'm pretty curious. A c# server/client is also fine. Let's do this.

async_read will only read a single message. You could try async_read_some which allows reading partial messages

@SteveLorimer how could that reduce scheduling contention/overhead? Seems to me that best case it is equivalent, but more code (due to lower-level interface)

If there are eg 2.5 messages in the socket receive buffer, async_read will return 1, but I would hope async_read_some could read the entire 2.5 messages into your local buffer

@SteveLorimer, nope, still 1 up to 1 message at a time.
